# Request Origin for Azure Web apps service

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an legacy Azure web app (with no application log), and I need to know from where the requests are coming to our server. Usually we get it from Server log. How can I get the server log for an Azure Web app.

Comment: does the legacy app has Application Insights option?

Comment: @the dev, any update on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Go to **App Service logs** under your app service, [enable web server logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-web-server-logging) there with storage or file system.

And about how to access the log file, check this [Access log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files). If you choose storage blob just go to your storage account check the file, if you choose file system, just go to `/LogFiles/http/RawLogs/` in your kudu site or download the zip file with `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump`.